# Testing @RequestParam via Rest Template

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I have a controller like that:

```
@GetMapping("listThem")
@ResponseBody
public List<String> listThem(@RequestParam Piece piece)
```

I want to test it via Rest Template. I've constructed piece object and tried that but didn't work:

```
String response = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/listThem?piece={piece}", String.class, piece);
```

I am not sure about do I need to construct object into JSON or not.

How can I test `@RequestParam` via Rest Template?

Comment: Try it by removing @RequestParam.

Comment: Can you show piece DTO? Why are you trying to de-serialize request parameter?